How to fix "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query'" in langchain?
retriver = PineconeVectorStore(
    pinecone_api_key=pc_key,
    index="index-1",
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings()
    ).as_retriever()


qa_chain = (
    {
        "context": retriver,
        "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
    }
    | review_template
    | model
    | StrOutputParser()
)

res =qa_chain.invoke("Question")
print(res)

Output of the code snipet : "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'query"
Expecting Output: retrive data from pinecone vectordb and create good answer for users.

You need to add the full traceback in all Python questions about errors.

This code does not refer to query anywhere, therefore the error must be happening inside other code.  Are we supposed to guess what that is?

I agree with both @thebjorn and John Gordon. Please add the full traceback or no one will be able to diagnose the problem, let alone solve it.
